# Is there a reliable International Currency Exchange rates provider in JSON format

Tags: programming, finance, currency, rates, exchange-rate

I am looking for a currency exchange rate provider (preferrably) JSON format ,  that is free/open and also reliable.

Anybody here have any experiences working with some solutions like this?

Cheers!!